# mySQL matching dates, and returning null on join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to combine some NBA data, box scores and advanced player stats. The query I've got at the moment is:

```
select boxes.GNO, boxes.NAME, boxes.DATE, advstat.YEAR, advstat.NAME, advstat.AGE
from boxes left join advstat on boxes.NAME=advstat.NAME
group by boxes.NAME, boxes.GNO having boxes.GNO = 1;
```

boxes.GNO=1 is just to limit the data returned at this point, ultimately I'll be returning data for all games in the boxes table.

With the query above I get the following output:

```
+------+------------------+------------+------+------------------+------+
| GNO  | NAME             | DATE       | YEAR | NAME             | AGE  |
+------+------------------+------------+------+------------------+------+
|    1 | Al Horford       | 2017-10-17 | 2008 | Al Horford       |   21 |
|    1 | Aron Baynes      | 2017-10-17 | 2013 | Aron Baynes      |   26 |
|    1 | Derrick Rose     | 2017-10-17 | 2009 | Derrick Rose     |   20 |
|    1 | Dwyane Wade      | 2017-10-17 | 2004 | Dwyane Wade      |   22 |
|    1 | Gordon Hayward   | 2017-10-17 | 2011 | Gordon Hayward   |   20 |
|    1 | Iman Shumpert    | 2017-10-17 | 2012 | Iman Shumpert    |   21 |
|    1 | Jae Crowder      | 2017-10-17 | 2013 | Jae Crowder      |   22 |
|    1 | Jaylen Brown     | 2017-10-17 | 2017 | Jaylen Brown     |   20 |
|    1 | Jayson Tatum     | 2017-10-17 | NULL | NULL             | NULL |
|    1 | Jeff Green       | 2017-10-17 | 2008 | Jeff Green       |   21 |
|    1 | JR Smith         | 2017-10-17 | NULL | NULL             | NULL |
|    1 | Kevin Love       | 2017-10-17 | 2009 | Kevin Love       |   20 |
|    1 | Kyle Korver      | 2017-10-17 | 2004 | Kyle Korver      |   22 |
|    1 | Kyrie Irving     | 2017-10-17 | 2012 | Kyrie Irving     |   19 |
|    1 | LeBron James     | 2017-10-17 | 2004 | LeBron James     |   19 |
|    1 | Marcus Smart     | 2017-10-17 | 2015 | Marcus Smart     |   20 |
|    1 | Semi Ojeleye     | 2017-10-17 | NULL | NULL             | NULL |
|    1 | Shane Larkin     | 2017-10-17 | 2014 | Shane Larkin     |   21 |
|    1 | Terry Rozier     | 2017-10-17 | 2016 | Terry Rozier     |   21 |
|    1 | Tristan Thompson | 2017-10-17 | 2012 | Tristan Thompson |   20 |
+------+------------------+------------+------+------------------+------+
```

This is almost right.. however I need advstat.YEAR to match year(boxes.DATE). If I add..
where year(boxes.DATE)=advstat.YEAR, the NULL data is excluded, which is not what I want. I need the table to look like it does above, only with the years lining up correctly between the 2 tables.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: Add the condition to the ON condition , that way nulls won’t be excluded .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select b.GNO, b.NAME, b.DATE, s.YEAR, s.NAME, s.AGE
from boxes b left join
     advstat s
     on b.NAME = s.NAME and year(b.date) = s.year
where b.GNO = 1
group by b.NAME, b.GNO ;
```

Note that filtering before the `group by` is usually more efficient, so I recommend `where` instead of `having`.

Comment: It is, you're a legend. Thanks mate!!